# How to assign string array into child element accodingly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How if I have string var `mydata="a1,a2,a3, ,a5,b1,b2,b3,b4,b5"` and I need assign into this element below?:-

```
Parent Index: 0 (div classname="parts")
.serialno="a1"
.modelno="a2"
.section="a3"
.subsection=" " -empty value
.incharge="a5"

Parent Index: 1 (div classname="parts")
.serialno="b1"
.modelno="b2"
.section="b3"
.subsection="b4 "
.incharge="b5"
```

What I already know is how to assign string array to element straight-forward like below:-

```
    var mydata = $("#txtproduction").val();
                var gdata = mydata.split(',').length / 5; //get how many group



           if (gdata = 1) {
                $.each(mydata.split(','), function (index, value) {                  
                    if (index == 0) { $('.serialno').val(value); }
                    if (index == 1) { $('.modelno').val(value); }
                    if (index == 2) { $('.section').val(value); }
                    if (index == 3) { $('.subsection').val(value); }
  if (index == 4) { $('.incharge').val(value); }
                });
            }
```

but when element has child inside parent I do not know how to handle it...

```
       if (gdata >1){
        //if more than 1 group data - how to handle loop assign value to element accondingly??

       }
```

Please help me, I already think many days, but still cannot figure out how to solve that problem.
Thanks on advance for reading and replying my questions.

Answer (score 1):

for element structure as below :

```
<div class="parts">
<input type="text" class="serialno">
<input type="text" class="modelno">
<input type="text" class="section">
<input type="text" class="subsection">
<input type="text" class="incharge">
</div>
<div class="parts">
<input type="text" class="serialno">
<input type="text" class="modelno">
<input type="text" class="section">
<input type="text" class="subsection">
<input type="text" class="incharge">
</div>
```

Below code should work :

```
var mydata = $("#txtproduction").val();            
var arr = mydata.split(',');
$('.serialno').each(function(i, o)     {$(this).val(arr[$(this).parent().index(".parts")*5]);});
$('.modelno').each(function(i, o) {$(this).val(arr[$(this).parent().index(".parts")*5+1]);});
$('.section').each(function(i, o) {$(this).val(arr[$(this).parent().index(".parts")*5+2]);});
$('.subsection').each(function(i, o) {$(this).val(arr[$(this).parent().index(".parts")*5+3]);});
$('.incharge').each(function(i, o) {$(this).val(arr[$(this).parent().index(".parts")*5+4]);});
```

Please correct my understanding if structure is different .
Check [here.](https://jsfiddle.net/yp476srs/8/)

Comment: Hello, thank ctor and #Walf where helping me regarding this matter. Honestly I already figure out by my own way to solve a problem before I saw this answer, but I still like your both solution and should have marks. I will try using yours code on future. Thanks again for helping and I really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to change the structure of `mydata`? You've got the same delimiter within and between records. You'd be better off joining records with a semicolon, e.g. `a1,a2,a3,a4,a5;b1,b2,b3,b4,b5;…`

If not, you need to 'chunk' your array.

```
var myData = $("#txtproduction").val().split(','),
    columnsPerRecord = 5,
    record;
while (myData.length) {
    // iterate/create div here
    record = myData.splice(0, columnsPerRecord);
    $(currentDiv).find('.serialno').val(record[0]);
    …
}
```